# Regex to find string inside string inside string

Tags: regex

Lets say I need to get a string inside some h1, h2, or h3 tags

```
/<[hH][1-3][^>]*>(.*?)<\/[hH][1-3]>/
```

This works great if the user decides to take a sane approach to headers:

```
<h1>My Header</h1>
```

but knowing my users, they want bold, italic, underlined h1's. And they have that coding quagmire tinyMCE to help them do it. TinyMCE would output:

```
<h1><b><span style='text-decoration: underline'><i>My Hideous Header</i></span></b></h1>
```

So my question is:

How do i get a string inside h1 h2, or h3, and then inside any amount of surrounding other tags as well?

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: What about this? `<h1><b>My <i>Hideous</i> Header</b></h1>` Would you want to retrieve the full title string with its embedded `<i>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in php you can use your regex:

`/<[hH][1-3][^>]*>(.*?)<\/[hH][1-3]>/`

then pass the captured result through strip_tags() function to get rid of all the insanity inside.

If you are not on php you can pass the result through regexp replace that removes tags. Something like replace 
`/<\/?[^>]+?>/` 
with empty string.

Answer (score 3):

```
/<(h[1-3])[^>]*>(?:.*?>)?([^<]+)(?:<.*?)?<\/\1>/i
```

It will not be too hard to make cases that break it hideously, since (as I'm sure people will tell you) parsing HTML is a job for an HTML parser, not a regex, but it works for your given case and various similar ones.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to capture the ultimately nested text you could just drop all tags inside the header tag with:

```
/<([hH][1-3]).*>(.*?)<.*\/$1>/
```

Untested, but I think it should work.

Comment: Nope. `(.*?)` is allowed to match nothing, and thanks to the greedy `.*` ahead of it, that's exactly what it does.